# Add Series Transition/Animation in Highchart Maps

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, maps, transition

[image: Maps transition with Higchart Maps]

Is it possible to add transitions/animations like the GIF image above when *colorAxis.dataClasses/legends* and *series* change using **Highchart Maps**?

I have tried this option, but it only works scale animation, not color.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allAreas: true,
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        },
    },

    ...
}
```

FYI: I'm using React.js, with <kbd>highcharts</kbd> and <kbd>highcharts-react-official</kbd> libraries

I really hope to get the answer.
Thank you in advance for all the responses and answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve animation during the update all you need to use is `colorAxis.update` method with the redraw flag set to true. You can check it in the demo below.

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-m1ectd
**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.ColorAxis#update

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I expected, but how do I slow down the transition duration during changing colorAxis?

Comment: You can set animation.duration on chart object.
Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-jf4upw
API Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-jf4upw